Order failed: 200-{"msg":"Funds increment invalid.","code":"400100"}
I'm using the kucoin api to check what is my USDT balance and purchase its equivalent in Bitcoin using Python 3.12.3
Now if I understand correctly there might be two problems:

the trade can be rejected if it's not a multiple of the quote increment provided by the api
This is more of my own worry, not sure if it's a real thing but I'm also worried about price fluctuations. So it could be that i fetch a certain price but it gets increase while the script runs. It's unlikely because we are talking about milliseconds but I think it's still possible

To solve these two problems, I leave a buffer of 0.01 USDT and I make sure that the trade amount is a multiple of the quote increment. You can see this in the below code:
from kucoin.client import Trade, User, Market

# Replace with your actual API credentials
api_key = 'my key'
api_secret = 'my secret'
api_passphrase = 'my passphrase'

# Initialize the KuCoin clients
trade_client = Trade(key=api_key, secret=api_secret, passphrase=api_passphrase)
user_client = User(key=api_key, secret=api_secret, passphrase=api_passphrase)
market_client = Market(key=api_key, secret=api_secret, passphrase=api_passphrase)

# Get account balances
account_balances = user_client.get_account_list()

# Find the USDT balance
usdt_balance = next((item for item in account_balances if item['currency'] == 'USDT' and item['type'] == 'trade'), None)

# Check if there is enough USDT balance
if usdt_balance and float(usdt_balance['balance']) > 0:
    total_usdt_amount = float(usdt_balance['balance'])
    buffer_amount = 0.01  # Leaving 0.01 USDT as buffer
    usdt_amount = total_usdt_amount - buffer_amount
    
    # Get the symbol info to find the quote increment and minimum size
    symbol_info = market_client.get_symbol_list()
    btc_usdt_info = next(item for item in symbol_info if item['symbol'] == 'BTC-USDT')
    quote_increment = float(btc_usdt_info['quoteIncrement'])
    quote_min_size = float(btc_usdt_info['quoteMinSize'])
    
    # Adjust USDT amount to be a multiple of quote_increment
    usdt_amount = (usdt_amount // quote_increment) * quote_increment

    if usdt_amount < quote_min_size:
        print(f"Order amount is too small, minimum required is {quote_min_size} USDT")
    else:
        # Create the market order to trade all USDT for BTC
        try:
            order = trade_client.create_market_order('BTC-USDT', 'buy', funds=str(usdt_amount))
            print(f"Order successful: Traded {usdt_amount} USDT for BTC")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Order failed: {e}")
else:
    print("Insufficient USDT balance or USDT balance not found")

Like you can see, I update the amount this way:
usdt_amount = (usdt_amount // quote_increment) * quote_increment

Which I thought it was correct, but probably I'm missing something because it gives me this error:
Order failed: 200-{"msg":"Funds increment invalid.","code":"400100"}


What exactly is the ustd_amount you end up transmitting? Probably include that information in the exception message.

It's my amound of USDT available in the kucoin account

The actual value stored in the variable, not a human-readable description of what it represents.

Canonical Answer
Your problem likely stems from using floating point numbers, which are not precisely accurate, so instead of 19.99 you probably have 19.990000000000002, for example. That's what I got trying your solution in a python interpreter:
>>> funds = 20
>>> increment = float(0.01)
>>> (funds // increment) * increment
19.990000000000002

You just need to round the number to the nearest hundreth, which you can do using round(), passing 2 as the second argument to round to 2 decimal places:
>>> round((funds // increment) * increment, 2)
19.99

Case-Specific Answer
Since the increment changes, you can't always use 2 as the second argument, but since quoteIncrement is given as a string from the API, you could just look at its length to determine what the argument should be. You don't need division at all this way:
>>> funds = 20.00023230234234
>>> quoteIncrement = "0.000001"
>>> len(quoteIncrement) - 2  # subtract 2 for the initial `0.`
6
>>> round(funds, len(quoteIncrement) - 2)
20.000232


Would probably be better off not using floats at all for money calculations.
